# How to output error when input is not "q" and not doubles with scanner

Tags: java

```
public class CurrencyConverter
{
double dollar;
double rate; //constructors
double euro;
```

//constuctors

```
public CurrencyConverter()
{
    dollar=0;
    rate=0.95;
}
```

//objects

```
public void setDollar(double d)
{
     dollar= d;
}
public double getCurrency()
{
 euro= rate*dollar;
 return euro;
```

How to output error when input is not "q" and not doubles in my code
I tried to use if method but it's not working

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CurrencyTester {

    private static Scanner in;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CurrencyConverter one = new CurrencyConverter();
        System.out.println("Convert dollar to euro");
        System.out.println("");

        do {
            System.out.println("Enter Dollars:");
            in = new Scanner(System.in);
            String d = in.next();
            if ("Q".equalsIgnoreCase(d)) {
                System.out.println("Stop!");
                break;
            } else {
                double ds = Double.parseDouble(d);
                one.setDollar(ds);
                System.out.println("Euro:");
                System.out.println(one.getCurrency());
            }
        } while (true);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part is correct when you check if your input is q or not, you need to check of your input is double or not, so you can use `try{}catch(){}` like this :

```
do {
    System.out.println("Enter Dollars:");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String d = in.next();
    if ("Q".equalsIgnoreCase(d)) {
        System.out.println("Stop!");
        break;
    } else {
        //check if your input is valid double or not, if not show an error message
        try {
            double ds = Double.parseDouble(d);
            one.setDollar(ds);
            System.out.println("Euro:");
            System.out.println(one.getCurrency());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("*********Not double*********");
        }
    }
} while (true);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Scanner` class has useful methods like:

- [`hasNextDouble()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextDouble()) - returns `true` if next token is a valid double
- [`hasNext(String pattern)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext(java.lang.String)) - returns `true` if next token matches the given pattern

Using these methods, you can easily check if your input matches a `double`, the character `'q'` or `'Q'`, or is none of the above:

```
try (Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Enter a double (q to quit)");
        if (in.hasNextDouble()) {
            double ds = in.nextDouble();
            System.out.printf("ds = %f%n", ds);
        } else if (in.hasNext("[qQ]")) {
            in.nextLine();  // clear out from 'q' to end of line
            System.out.println("Stop!");
            break;
        } else {
            String bad_input = in.next();
            System.out.println("Not a double: " + bad_input);
            in.nextLine();  // clear out all invalid input to end of line
        }
    }
}
```

**Note** the use of `in.nextLine();` to clear out the input stream until the `\n` character has been consumed, both for when bad input is encountered, and when a single `q` word has been encountered.

Answer (score -1):

You said if `d` is not "Q" **AND** `ds` is not a double. I'll take that literally. If not "Q", your current implementation will break out of the while-loop before evaluating the double.

1. You need to change that.
2. Use a try...catch block to handle a `NumberFormatException` when trying to parse a `double` from the input string.

Here is a new cut at the while loop:

```
do { 
    boolean isQ = true;
    boolean isDouble = true;
    System.out.println("Enter Dollars:");
    in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String d = in.next();

    isQ = ("Q".equalsIgnoreCase(d)) {   
    if(isQ) {
        try {
            double ds = Double.parseDouble(d);
            one.setDollar(ds);
            System.out.println("Euro:");
            System.out.println(one.getCurrency());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            isDouble = false;
        }
    } 
    if (!isQ && !isDouble) {
        // some error message
    } 
} while(true);
```